# get a text from xptha using selenium and phpunit

Tags: selenium, phpunit

```
<table id="RegTable" class="GSTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 20px auto 0px; width: 580px; padding: 5px; font-size: 12px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="termstab" height="150" colspan="2">
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; padding-right:5px; overflow-y:auto;">
<p align="justify"></p>
<h2 class="paraHead" align="center">Terms and Conditions</h2>
```

how can i verify 'Terms and Conditions' text from this web page. i tried verifyTextPresent method and other possible methode, but it does not work. So i need to locate the path. How can i get text 'Terms and Conditions' from that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various ways...

Via XPath would be:

```
//h2[text()='Terms and Conditions']
```

or

```
//h2[@class='paraHead']
```

or

```
//table[@id='RegTable']/descendant::h2[text()='Terms and Conditions']
```

or using CSS:

```
h2.parahead
```

Comment: i am trying to get text 'Terms and Conditions' from that location . i used $this->getText(//table[@id='RegTable']/descendant::h2[text()='Terms and Conditions']) but it does not work